# Grails: Locate file on web-app on production

Tags: ios, grails, apple-push-notifications, grails-config

i have a file locate in web-app in my grails project.. in the config file for some apns plugin in put the config as the following

```
    environments {
    development {
        apns {
            pathToCertificate = "web-app/apns-dev.p12"
            password = "password"
            environment = "sandbox"
        }
    }
    test {
        apns {
            pathToCertificate = "web-app/apns-dev.p12"
            password = "password"
            environment = "sandbox"
        }
    }

    production {
        apns {
            pathToCertificate = "apns-prod.p12"
            password = "password"
            environment = "production"
        }
    }
}
```

the reason i put the p12 of production without "web-app" is because i've noticed that the file located on production under the root directrly but it give me fileNotFoundException.. so how can i locate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [apns plugin page](http://grails.org/plugin/apns) states

> If you don't have access to your server's file system, you can also replace pathToCertificate by certificateResourcePath and set it to the path of your certificate, relative to src/java. So for example, if your certificate is in src/java/mycert.p12, you can set certificateResourcePath=mycert.p12.

This is probably your best bet, allowing you to use paths relative to src/java rather than absolute paths.

Comment: nah not working .. i wish we have some sort of a way to have an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (slighty hacky) way to get the file's absolute path:

First, put the files on the `classpath` somewhere (e.g. a "resources" directory inside the `conf` directory). Then, change your `pathToCertificate` line to:

```
pathToCertificate = ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.getResource("classpath:resources/apns-dev.p12").file.absolutePath
```

which should resolve to the absolute path for that file on your file system.

Comment: well it gives me error on compile 

| Error Error packaging application: Error loading Config.groovy: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigObject.getResource() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [classpath:web-app/WEB-INF/apns-dev.p12]